# Is there any point flagging a question that has an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, voting, flags, moderation

I've just been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031464/progressdialog-in-android).  Even if it was cleaned up, it would essentially boil down to: 'How do you use `ProgressDialog` in a `TabHost` application for Android?'.  To me, the question is overly broad and shows little engagement/effort from the OP, so I downvoted it.  On this occasion, I didn't leave a comment.  The question has since been upvoted 3 times, answered (the answer consisted of look at this other website, which didn't mention `TabHost`), and the answer has been accepted.

So, I guess I have a couple of questions

- Am I being overly strict in my interpretation of what a valid question is?  In a time where there's quite a bit of talk about there not being enough voting on questions, it seems odd that what seems to me to be a bad question has had such a positive response.
- Is there any point flagging questions when they have accepted answers?  I know one of my work colleagues has flagged questions in the past, which have been answered and accepted before the moderator has got to the question to subsequently dismiss the flag as invalid.  Will moderator's close questions, if there's an accepted answer?

As a general observation (party related), there seems to be a disparity between the expectations of different sub communities on SO.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031394/hey-im-writing-a-simple-socket-program-to-send-and-receive-udp-packets-using-wins) in the C++ tag, which showed some effort on the part of the OP, although it was far from an ideal question, quickly acquired 4 down votes.

Comment: Yes, there's still a point in flagging bad questions with accepted answers. An accepted answer doesn't prevent others from posting their own answer to the question later. It's not the same as being closed.

Comment: I voted to close as NARQ ("overly broad") and added a downvote. There is a point to flagging if the question is bad enough to warrant deletion, although it would be unusual for such a question to get three upvotes.

Comment: And by the way, exactly *what* effort does [that C++ question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031394/hey-im-writing-a-simple-socket-program-to-send-and-receive-udp-packets-using-wins) show? The entire question consists of a wall of code. It's basically asking "debug this for me". And that's not even a question.

Comment: @Cody Gray: HAH!  I said it wasn't ideal :) Some effort... They described a problem (albeit in the title, not the question), showed their workings (albeit in one block of code that wasn't formatted properly).  The main missing was more error details & engagement by the OP in comments, which as they are a new user, *could* have modified their behaviour going forward (most of the downvotes were cast before any comments had been made).  As it turns out, the OP wasn't engaged, so they didn't get a solution, but for me they had a better starting point...

Comment: let me get this straight--you think the question is low quality, but others have shown their disagreement with your opinion by providing answers and upvoting the question?  And you want mods to do exactly what with this question?

Comment: @Will don't give a: That may answer my question... If I'd flagged the question as NARQ straight away, I think there's a reasonable chance it would have been closed.  The question really is, is having an accepted answer enough to predetermine the outcome of any flagging at this point, i.e. "somebody's answered it, it must be a real question", or do the moderators always judge the question based around their interpretation of the defined remit of the site, regardless of what those community members that have interacted with a question (which will be a minority of the site's users)  have done?

Comment: @forsvarir: Well, there really isn't any definitive rule we can follow when judging this.  It is all subjective.  One of the things you have to keep reminding yourself as a moderator is that your opinion really doesn't matter any more than any other user of the system (well, 10k+ users).  Therefore, it sometimes is better to not act on a flag than to impose your judgement every single time.  The more subjective the action, the better to leave it to the community.  In this particular case, I'd almost always let the judgement of the community decide--one flag vs 1+ votes/answers

Comment: @forsvarir: Of course, depending on the moderator.... I think the only legit reason to flag as low quality is to indicate the user has demonstrated that they are more than happy to ask awful questions, over and over.  Any other reason I can think of can be solved by editing.